# Pandas groupby mean to another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I am a newcomer to Pandas and I don't fully understand how pd.groupby works.

Say I have a dataframe with datetime:

```
Date          City    Sales  Price
2018-01-01     NY      100     1
2018-01-01     NY      120     2
2018-01-01     NY       85     1.4
2018-01-01     LA       90     1.5
2018-01-01     SF       90     1
2018-01-01     SF       75     1

2018-01-02     NY      110     2
2018-01-02     NY      130     1.8
2018-01-02     NY      190     1.1
2018-01-02     LA      100     0.9
2018-01-02     LA      110     1.2
2018-01-02     LA      120     1.0
2018-01-02     LA       50     1.8
2018-01-02     SF      120     1.1

2018-01-03     NY       90     1.1
2018-01-03     LA       90     1.5
...
and so on
```

So I have several Cities, and several Sales in each city at different Price.
I need a new dataframe, that would contain statistics on daily
Price (mean = SUMM(Price)/N) and 
mean_weighted = SUMM(Price*Sales)/SUMM(Sales), or as an option: 
normal distribution parameters) for each City and Date.

So it would look like

```
Date           NY_mean NY_mean_w LA_mean LA_mean_w SF_mean SF_mean_w 
2018-01-01     1.466      1.53      1.5     1.5       1       1
2018-01-02     1.633      1.54      1.03    and so on
2018-01-03     ...
2018-01-04     ...
2018-01-05     ...
...
```

Is there any way to avoid Fortran-like summations with nested loops and subroutines? I am trying (only for mean value):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_pickle('path/data.pkl') # here is original data

index = pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-01', end = '2015-12-31', freq='D')

names = data.City.unique() # unique names
data_stat = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
data_stat = data_stat.fillna(0)

for nm in names: # iterate by name
    print(nm)
    data_stat.name = data [(data.City == nm)].groupby(Data).Price.mean()
data_stat.head()
```

But that gives me NaN in all cells.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df = (df.assign(W=df['Sales'].mul(df['Price']))
        .groupby(['Date','City']).agg({'Price':'mean', 'W':'sum', 'Sales':'sum'})
        .assign(WM = lambda x: x['PW'].div(x['Sales']))[['Price','WM']]
        .rename(columns={'Price':'MEAN'})
        .unstack()
        .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=0))

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
            LA_MEAN     LA_WM   NY_MEAN     NY_WM  SF_MEAN  SF_WM
Date                                                             
2018-01-01    1.500  1.500000  1.466667  1.504918      1.0    1.0
2018-01-02    1.225  1.136842  1.633333  1.541860      1.1    1.1
2018-01-03    1.500  1.500000  1.100000  1.100000      NaN    NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. First multiple columns `Sales` and `Price` to new column `W` with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html)
2. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean` and `sum`s by columns names
3. Create column `WM` by `assign` and divide again
4. Select only necessary columns by subset `[[]]`
5. `Rename` column `Price`
6. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
7. `swaplevel` `MultiIndex` in columns
8. [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) - first level of `MultiIndex`
9. Flatten `MultiIndex` to columns names by `map` and `join`

Comment: @user3656916 - give me some time for explanation.